# Is there an elementary proof that the Mertens function is not $O(x^\theta)$ if $\theta <1/2$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

The Mertens function is the partial sums of the Moebius function:
$M(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)$
Since the zeta-function has a zero on the critical line it follows that $M(x)\ne O(x^\theta)$ for any $\theta<\frac 12$.

Does anyone know if there is an elementary proof of this statement?  (By elementary I mean a proof which does not depend on complex analysis, in particular the existance of a zero of $\zeta$).  even an elementary proof of $M(x)$ being unbounded would be interesting to me.

Comment: You might enjoy reading the answers to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11074/partial-sums-of-multiplicative-functions

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, even an elementary proof that $M(x)$ is unbounded is not known.

Comment: Note that the function field analogue of M(x) is bounded (no zeroes for the analogous zeta function), so this already rules out a fairly large class of elementary proofs; one needs to somehow use a property of the rational integers that is not shared by the polynomials over a finite field.